# Converting multiple year ranges into a list of years in R

Tags: r, list, date

I have a column of dates from which I am trying to create a list of years for each row.  For example, this is a few rows of my data:

```
1997-2001
1994
2007-2009; 2013-2015; 2016
2007-2008; 2014
```

For example, for the first row I want a list containing: 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000 and 2001.  For the second row I want a list containing just 1994. For the 3rd row I want a list containing: 2007, 2008, 2009, 2013, 2014, 2015, and 2016. and so on like this.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what data type does your column hold? string or what? can you possibly `dput` your column here?

Comment: Here are some solutions, though I don't know which would be best recommended: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/convert-delimited-strings-with-ranges-to-numeric-td4673763.html

Answer (score 4):

It's ugly, but it gets the job done:

```
lapply(strsplit(df$date,'\\s*;\\s*'),function(x) unlist(lapply(strsplit(x,'-'),function(y) { z <- as.integer(y); if (length(z)==1L) z else z[1L]:z[2L]; })));
## [[1]]
## [1] 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 1994
##
## [[3]]
## [1] 2007 2008 2009 2013 2014 2015 2016
##
## [[4]]
## [1] 2007 2008 2014
##
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(date=c('1997-2001','1994','2007-2009; 2013-2015; 2016','2007-2008; 2014'),
stringsAsFactors=F);
```

---

Note: If your input vector is a factor, as opposed to a character vector, then you'll have to wrap it in `as.character()` before passing it to the initial `strsplit()` call.

Comment: if I want to create a list for each row within a for loop (because I want to do other things with other variables in the given row), do I still need to use lapply? thanks!

Comment: You can use the result of the `lapply()` call in your loop, provided your iterator is a row index. There's no benefit to individually running the splitting/sequencing logic within each iteration of the loop; you might as well precompute the whole thing, and then just access each element as needed.

Comment: when I run your code above, I get the following error: Error in strsplit(history$Term, "\\s*;\\s*") : non-character argument

Comment: @DebMartin Sorry, I should have addressed the issue of factor vs. character input. You'll need an `as.character()` coercion for that case. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

bgoldst's answer resolved the problem but here's another way you could do it.

You can use `gsub` to convert your semicolons to commas and dashes to colons like so (where df is the data frame and x is the column containing the data):

```
df$x<-gsub("-",":",df$x)
df$x<-gsub(";",",",df$x)
```

which would give you:

```
1997:2001
1994
2007:2009, 2013-2015, 2016
2007:2008, 2014
```

Then use a for-loop to evaluate all those expressions:

```
years<-list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
     years[i]<-list(eval(parse(text=paste("c(",df$x[i],")"))))
}
```

As above, if your input is a vector of factors rather than characters, you will need to replace `df$x[i]` with `as.character(df$x[i])`.